# "Anti-private" property of setter method

Tags: ruby, setter, accessor

**Getter** methods can be used without an explicit receiver unless there is a local variable with the same name:

```
class A; attr_reader :foo end
A.new.instance_eval do
  @foo = :foo
  p foo
end
# => :foo
```

This will not hold when there is a local variable with the same name, due to the principle that interpretation as a local variable has priority than as a method call whenever there is an ambiguity.

```
class A; attr_reader :foo end
A.new.instance_eval do
  foo = :bar
  @foo = :foo
  p foo
end
# => :bar
```

However, **setter** methods cannot be used without an explicit receiver even when a local variable with the same name is not assigned prior to the expression in question:

```
class A; attr_writer :foo end
A.new.instance_eval do
  foo = :foo  # <= No local variable named `foo` has been assigned before this point
  p @foo
end
# => nil
```

How is this "anti-private" property of setter method justified?

Comment: how is this "anti-private" ? i don't get it. Setters are not private methods.

Comment: @m_x They are not. I am writing anti-private. Not private.

Comment: why the heck would a setter be private ? the whole point of a setter is to expose a field to the public interface. Or maybe i don't understand what you mean by "anti-private"

Comment: @m_x Do you even know what private means in Ruby? It means it cannot take an explicit receiver. By "anti-private" I mean it obligatorily needs a receiver.

Comment: I've never seen attr_reader and attr_writer without arguments.  What's happening in these snippets?

Comment: @WayneConrad Those are my cricial typos. I will correct them. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @sawa `private` in ruby defines exposure, so m_x is absolutely right to call you on this one. It may be unclear what you mean by anti-private, and even though I understand you mean that the object does not implicitly use setters when variables are defined in its (in your words private) scope, there is no need to get rude over this.

Comment: @BeatRichartz I don't get what you mean by "exposure". I also don't get how scope is relevant to my question. I further don't get what you mean by "private scope". What is that?

Comment: `class A; private; def b; puts 'can you call me?'; end; end`. If you instantiate `A` and try to call `b`, a `NoMethodError` is raised. So the method `b` is not exposed by the instantiated object.

Comment: @BeatRichartz You did not show how `b` is called. Whether an error is raised depends on that.

Comment: @sawa the word `private` is yours. The scope of an object is where it contains its local and instance variables. For example, if you do instance eval with an object you gain access to its scope.

Comment: @BeatRichartz It is not mine, it is the official definition. And how is that scope relevant to my question? And "private scope" is your creation. I never used the words here in that combination. I does not make sense to me.

Comment: @sawa Please try reading for comprehension.

Comment: Yes, i know what private means in ruby. Your question would better be rephrased as "Why do setters need an explicit receiver in ruby ?". I think @BeatRichards explained it well. As a side note, AFAIK "anti-private" is an invention of yours and is nowhere to be found on the official docs, so please stop looking down upon people that honestly try to understand you question and help you.

Comment: @m_x Yes, "Why do setters need an explicit receiver?" would mean the same thing, but it would not make difference except it's more verbose. Why would it need to be rephrased that way? And indeed "anti-private" is my invention, and that is why I put it in double quotes. That should be obvious. Why would you try to find that in the docs? And to infer the meaning of it from the meaning of private should be straightforward if you understood the meaning of the latter.

Comment: By "anti-private" I think you meant "non-private". Using "anti-" can be confusing because that prefix often contains the idea of being "against" or "opposed"; while "non-" simply means "not". But either way you phrase it, I don't see how access control is related to needing or not needing an explicit receiver.

Comment: @Kelvin Private means it **cannot** have an explicit receiver. Negation of that would be that it **may** have an explicit receiver, which is not what I am mentioning. I am mentioning a case where a method **must** have an explicit receiver, which is against private. I think you are confused.

Answer (score 5):

If ruby interpreted your assignment in your last statement as an assignment to `self`, you would have no way left to set a local variable.

The way it is leaves no ambiguity for the interpreter to deal with: assignments without `self` are always local variables, assignments to self are always trying to use a writer on the object.

### If it were the other way around

The interpreter would have to look up the contexts writer methods and assign it via the writer if there is one, which almost certainly would have a negative impact on performance

```
class A
  attr_writer :foo
end

A.new.instance_eval do
  # for each of these assignments, the interpreter has to look up if there's
  # a writer method defined
  foo = 'bar' 
  bar = 'baz'
  fib = 'buz'
end
```

It would also leave the programmer with the rather stupid task to find out every setter method of the context he's in before assigning local variables to make absolutely sure he does not unintentionally use a setter.

```
class C
  attr_writer :something
end

class B < C
  attr_writer :foo
end

class A < B
  attr_writer :bar
end

A.new.instance_eval
  something = 'something' 
  #you just (almost certainly with no intention) assigned a value to an attribute
end
```

Also, your question reads:

> setter methods cannot be used without an explicit receiver even when a
>   local variable with the same name is not assigned prior to the
>   expression in question:

If it were the other way around, you could not assign a local variable with the same name prior to the expression in question, because the assignment would use the setter (as stated in the first paragraph of this answer)

Concerning the implementation / the access to variables the attribute methods use: Getter and Setters work with instance variables. So, for example `attr_accessor` actually defines something like this:

```
 def foo
   @foo
 end

 def foo=(data)
   @foo = data
 end
```

So, the attribute is declared as a instance variable and not as a local variable, why should the programmer be able to assign it like a local variable? This would leave the wrong impression that you could assign instance variables of an object via assigning local variables. If ruby would do this, it would almost certainly lead to a serious memory management problem. To make it short: `foo = 'bar'` and `@foo = 'bar'` are not the same, and exactly because the `attr` methods use `@foo = 'bar'`, you can not call them via using `foo = 'bar'`.

Comment: It is actually interpreting it not as an assignment to `self`, but as a local variable.

Comment: That is opposite of what you said. On the other hand, if it is indeed what you said, then you are just repeating the question.

Comment: @sawa I clarified my answer a bit, hope it helps.

Comment: @sawa Maybe you missed the "if" in the answer's first sentence?

Comment: I cannot fully parse your third paragraph, but your third and fourth paragraphs seem to be answering my question from a design point of view. That is half an answer to my question, but I am expecting the other half: from the implementation point of view.

Comment: I may or may not have missed your "if". It was hard to get the intention.

Comment: @sawa I made an effort to clarify my points and answer your question. Hope it is clear now :)

Answer (score 1):

I think @sawa finally clarified what is meant by "anti-private".

sawa's comment:

> Private means it **cannot** have an explicit receiver. Negation of that would be that it **may** have an explicit receiver, which is not what I am mentioning. I am mentioning a case where a method **must** have an explicit receiver, which is against private. I think you are confused.

I was confused, apparently along with all the other commenters, because "anti-private" and "against private" aren't standard terminology, nor was the meaning immediately obvious.

I think the meaning of the original question is: "**Since setters require an explicit receiver, and `private` forbids explicit receivers, how can I call a `private` setter?**" In other words, "anti-private" means "*incompatible with `private`*", or "*unusable with `private`*".

Jörg W Mittag eloquently explains an [exception to the normal `private` rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10814553/498594). Basically, setters can be called on `self` even if they are private, because there's no other way to call them (unless you use the cumbersome `send`).

So, a setter's requirement of an explicit receiver is perfectly compatible with the setter being `private`, only because of the exception to the rule.

Comment: @sawa, I can't tell if you're the down-voter, but would you mind confirming or denying whether I'm understanding your question accurately? I still want to get to the bottom of what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Beat Richartz's answer is pretty complete already, but I want to highlight one point about the behavior you're proposing.

In your question you have this sample code:

```
class A; attr_writer :foo end
A.new.instance_eval do
  foo = :foo  # <= No local variable named `foo` has been assigned before this point
  p @foo
end
```

You are proposing that the assignment call the setter method. And you want this to happen if the local-variable `foo` hasn't been assigned yet.

But what syntax **would** you use to assign the local before that point?

If the receiverless assignment `foo = :foo` means call the setter (when it exists), you'd need yet another syntax construct to mean "*assign this local-variable, disregarding whether there is a setter*".

I honestly do want to hear your proposal (I'm not being sarcastic) if you have one. It would be interesting to hear alternative views on language design.

I'm not saying your way would be necessarily "worse" than the current ruby way. But at some point a language designer has to decide default behaviors for ambiguous situations, and Matz decided that receiverless assignment assigns the local.