# When using a private attr_accessor, why does self.attribute= work, but self.attribute doesn't?

Tags: ruby

Suppose I have a class where I define an `attr_accessor` like so:

```
private

attr_accessor :attribute
```

I understand why using the `self.attribute` reader method doesn't work - in Ruby you can't call a private method on an explicit receiver.

What I'm confused by is why doesn't this rule apply to the writer? Why can I call `self.attribute = 1`, and that doesn't throw any access violation errors?

Comment: Without actually doing any research I would guess it's because the `self.` is needed to disambiguate it from assigning a local variable.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking it has to do it this way because of that. I guess I'm manly wondering if its a special case to prevent ambiguous calls like that, or if there was something about the object model I didn't understand that was allowing it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why won't Ruby allow me to specify self as a receiver inside a private method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811986/why-wont-ruby-allow-me-to-specify-self-as-a-receiver-inside-a-private-method)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the nominated exemplar.  The OP understands that you can't call a private method such as `attribute`  using `self.attribute`.  The question is why he _can_ call the private mutator using `self.attribute =`.  This is indeed surprising, and a good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to a comment by @Jörg W Mittag to Alan Skorkin's blog entry [Ruby Access Control – Are Private And Protected Methods Only A Guideline?](https://www.skorks.com/2010/04/ruby-access-control-are-private-and-protected-methods-only-a-guideline/):

> Quick note: there is a special case where calling private methods with an explicit receiver is allowed:
>
> If the method name ends with '=' (i.e. it is an attribute writer) and the explicit receiver is 'self', then this works. This is necessary, because setters can only be called with an explicit receiver because of the method/variable ambiguity. Otherwise it wouldn't be possible to call private setters.

Jörg cites no sources, but he's pretty reliable.